# wcf rest service 400 error : There might be a typing error in the address

Tags: wcf, rest

am trying to invoke wcf rest service from url  but its showing error like this Error : 
Most likely causes:
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If you clicked on a link, it may be out of date.

i need JSON responce for mobile apps

Here my code :

Iservice.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;


namespace SampleRestSample
{
   interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "Book/{id}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Prasad> GetBookById(string id);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Prasad
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Service1.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace LoginRestSample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class Service1 : SampleRestSample
    {
        List<Prasad> list = new List<Prasad>();
        public List<Prasad> GetBookById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                Prasad cls = new Prasad();
                cls.Age = "24";
                cls.Name = "prasad";
                list.Add(cls);

                //int bookId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

                //using (SampleDbEntities entities = new SampleDbEntities())
                //{
                //    return entities.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.ID == bookId);
                //}
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new FaultException("Something went wrong");
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRestSample.SampleRestSample">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfRestSample.ISampleRestSample" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/SampleRestSample" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

any solutions

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebGet instead of WebInvoke.
ALso add json end point.